# Display the Backstage tab by default?

Tags: wpf, ribbon, fluent, fluent-ribbon

I Have wpf application which has fluent ribbon control. I have 2 tabs,

File (backstage) and Home . By default Home tab is coming while loading the application. But i want 
to display the File tab (Backstage) has to come by default while loading my application.

please help..

thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

The backstage has an `IsOpen` property